# .htaccess retrieve from folder if subdomain, not 301 redirecting?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want my site to just point to /user folder if the request is a subdomain.

If the request is subdomain.site.com/admin, then the site should show the page for subdomain.site.com/user/admin.

The problem with my code is that it makes an 301 redirect instead of just keeping the url-address.

My code look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.bildsida.se(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+.bildsida.se(.*)

RewriteRule ^$ user/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) user/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

And you can try for yourself, go to http://mickes.bildsida.se/admin and see how the address changes to /user/admin. Very disturbing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! After days and nights of reading forums and documentations, and testing all possible ways, I got it to work!

**Sulotion:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.bildsida.se
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bildsida.se

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^$ user/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)? user/$1/ [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule /(.+)/ user/$1 [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a few of the lines you showed to get this working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.bildsida.se
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.bildsida\.se

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user/$1 [L]
```

I adjusted the HTTP_HOST checks because that parameter only looks at the domain name, so you don't need the (.*) at the end. I also removed the checks that look if the file exists or is a directory, since you want everything redirected (no reason to make it possible to access files from other subdomains, for example)

Comment: I get "Internal Server Error" now. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You code can be simplified to these lines : (try them instead)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?bildsida\.se [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Still get "Internal Server Error" :/

Comment: If you access directly the file (in user) do you get internal server error or does it work perfectly ?

Comment: No, I still get "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Then you should check your code, the internal server error may not be coming from the htaccess

Comment: But, my code in the question works fine except the redirect. Notably is that it actually works to type the exact path, like "mickes.bildsida.se/admin/index.php". That address gets /user/admin/index.php, like it should do even without /index.php.